# HTML/CSS table cell and/or content not respecting inherited height

Tags: html, css

Currently I am trying to make a table with 2 rows, each having 5 images. It's nested in a div with a 100% width and 200px height attribute.
Now I want to even out the space, eg. each table cell using 20% width and 50% height.

The images/cells respect the 20% width just fine, the image scales according to the container div width. Unfortunately it outright seems to ignore the height attribute. It will just scale up the image when the div becomes wider, no matter the height attribute while the height should be capped at approx 100px.

How would I go about getting each table cell and image/content stick to 20% width and 50% height of the topbar div? I am probably missing something simple, but I cannot find it for the life of me.

Here is my html, css and jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kav2yan5/

```
<div class="topbar">
  <div class="logos">
    <table class="logotable">
      <tr class="logorow">
        <td class="logocell"><img src=""></td>
        <td class="logocell"><img src=""></td>
        <td class="logocell"></td>
        <td class="logocell"><img src=""></td>
        <td class="logocell"><img src=""></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="logorow">
        <td class="logocell"><img src=""></td>
        <td class="logocell"><img src=""></td>
        <td class="logocell"></td>
        <td class="logocell"><img src=""></td>
        <td class="logocell"><img src=""></td>        
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.topbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.logotable {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.logocell {
  height: 50%;
  width: 20%;
}
.logocell img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Do you want the image to not stretch to a height higher than 100px? [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/kav2yan5/1/)?

Comment: One problem is that the table is in a block with `width: auto` and `height:auto`. If you change the css, giving a specific width and height to `.logos`, you will see that the table will respond to the sizes as well. [new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/kav2yan5/2/). However, the table will treat sizes as min-sizes. This is normal.

Comment: @remdevtec Yes, though I did not want to specify it for the sake of responsive design. MrLister: Same as the previous, I tried to avoid specifying it even though its a pain in CSS. Thank you both though. I did avoid it now by moving to was 5 column div setup instead of a table.

Comment: @MrLister Obviously previous comment for you too, thank you.